# Modifying camera location based on keypress

Tags: c++, directx-9, directinput

I have an application which renders graphics onscreen using DirectX. The default view of first person is set using the below code, setting the Y axis to 0. The code is contained within the SetupCamera() function which is called prior to Render().

```
 D3DXVECTOR3 vCamera(5.0f, 0.0f, -45.0f);
```

I am using DirectInput to manage user input. I want to be able to allow the user to press SPACE and change the Y axis value to 90 to switch to a top down view, then press again to switch it back. I currently have the below code in my ProcessKeyboardInput() function, called prior to Render().

```
if (KEYDOWN(buffer, DIK_SPACE))
{
  \\ ???    
}
```

but I am unsure what I need to do to allow the user to adjust the value which doesn't interrupt the rendering. I must be missing something simple here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Full CameraSetup() code...

```
void SetupCamera()
{
// Setup View Matrix
D3DXVECTOR3 vCamera(5.0f, 0.0f, -45.0f);    // camera location  x,y,z plane
D3DXVECTOR3 vLookat(5.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);      // camera direction x,y,z plane
D3DXVECTOR3 vUpVector(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    // which way is up x,y,z plane
    D3DXMATRIX matView;
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH( &matView, &vCamera, &vLookat, &vUpVector);
    D3D_Device -> SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);


 // Setup Projection Matrix to transform 2D geometry into 3D space
 D3DXMATRIX matProj;
     D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProj, D3DX_PI/4, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
     D3D_Device -> SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj);
}
```

Full ProcessKeyboardInput() code...

```
void WINAPI ProcessKeyboardInput()
{ 
// Define a macro to represent the key detection predicate
#define KEYDOWN(name, key) (name[key] & 0x80) 

// Create buffer to contain keypress data
char     buffer[256];
HRESULT  hr;

// Clear the buffer prior to use
ZeroMemory(&buffer, 256);

 hr = g_pDIKeyboardDevice -> GetDeviceState(sizeof(buffer),(LPVOID)&buffer); 
if FAILED(hr) 
{ 
    // If device state cannot be attained, check if it has been lost and try to      aquire it again
    hr = g_pDIKeyboardDevice -> Acquire();
    while (hr == DIERR_INPUTLOST) hr = g_pDIKeyboardDevice -> Acquire();

    hr = g_pDIKeyboardDevice -> GetDeviceState(sizeof(buffer),(LPVOID)&buffer); 
} 

bool topView = false;

if (KEYDOWN(buffer, DIK_Q))
{
    // 'Q' has been pressed - instruct the application to exit.
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}

if (KEYDOWN(buffer, DIK_SPACE))
{
    // Space has been pressed - swap from 1st person view to overhead view

    // topView is true
 topView = !topView;

 // if topView is true, adjust camera accordingly
 if (topView) 
    {
        vCamera.y = 90.f;
    } 
    else        // if untrue, set camera to 1st person
        {
            vCamera.y = 0.f;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Don't worry about "interrupt the rendering". There is a lot of processing going on between render calls in any graphics application. How about something like this:

```
// Have this somewhere appropriate in the code
bool topView = false;

if (KEYDOWN(buffer, DIK_SPACE))
{
    // Toggle top view
    topView = !topView;

    // Set camera vector
    if (topView) {
        vCamera.y = 90.f;
    } else {
        vCamera.y = 0.f:
    }
}
```

After updating, you need to send your matrices to DirectX again. Basically you need to call the following chunk of code again now that the `vCamera` (or any of the other view vectors) have been changed. I'd suggest bundling the code up in  the `SetupCamera()` function and call it in the `Render()` function, after checking for user input. That would also require to move `vCamera` etc out outside the function so that other functions can use them.

```
// vCamera, vLookat, vUpVector defined outside function

// Call this in rendering loop to set up camera
void SetupCamera() {
    // Calculate new view matrix from view vectors
    D3DXMATRIX matView;
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH( &matView, &vCamera, &vLookat, &vUpVector);
    D3D_Device -> SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);

    // Setup Projection Matrix to transform 2D geometry into 3D space
    D3DXMATRIX matProj;
    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProj, D3DX_PI/4, 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
    D3D_Device -> SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response on this Victor :)  - I understand the logic of your suggestion, looks good - but i'm getting 'identifier vCamera' is undefined after implementing it (I placed the bool within the ProcessKeyboardInput function after the device has been setup). 
I know that is a scope error, but i'm unsure how to correctly reference vCamera.y here. I tried moving

    D3DXVECTOR3 vCamera(5.0f, 0.0f, -45.0f);

out of the SetupCamera function and making it global, and although the error then disappears, pressing space doesn't change the view, grr

Comment: Show the whole SetupCamera and Render functions, sounds like there is a call in there somewhere that lets DirectX know what vector to use - probably using matrix multiplications (not familiar with DirectX).

Comment: i'll keep having a play with it anyway - your initial idea has helped a lot - thanks again